# Windows 8 Metro app: blur animation filter on an image

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Does anyone know or have any hints as to how I could animate a blur of an image from focus to blur over the course of about 1 second?

Essentially the same question as this, but on Windows 8!
[Animating a gaussian blur using core animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748404/animating-a-gaussian-blur-using-core-animation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a blurred version of the image - e.g. using WriteableBitmapEx and then overlay the blurred version on top of the original and animate its opacity from 0 to 1.

Alternatively - you could do DirectX interop and animate a property bound to a pixel shader input that controls the blurriness, though that might be a bit more work.

Comment: Thanks for the opacity idea! I'll give it a go, as it may be good enough for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Blur isn't an animation in the WinRT Animation Library for Xaml
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.aspx#classes

What are you trying to accomplish by the blur?

Have you tried this animation?
 - FadeOutThemeAnimation

Comment: Hi there, I'd like to give a bit of depth to my app, so when the user wants to edit meta data of a photo, the photo animates "out of focus" and the text editing controls appear. Just thought it would be a beautiful effect. I wonder if the only option is C++/Direct2D and render it myself? Hmmmm

Comment: Interesting idea but what if the metadata about a photo has to do with the details in the photo - bluring it would be counterproductive.  Simulating depth on a 2D screen with effects or drop shadows isn't consistent with Metro's Authentically Digital principle. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh781237.aspx