# Find an animation of text switching

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

How to achieve this text switching animation? Each character has changes in opacity, position, and blur.
Opacity and position are working. I can't find a way to blur.
like this：

```
func runTextAnimationPostion_Show() -> Void {
    isShowing = true
    for (idx,item) in textLayers.enumerated() {
        item.position = textLayerPostions[idx];
        item.removeAllAnimations();
        item.opacity = 0.0
    }
    
    for (index,textLayer) in textLayers.enumerated() {
        
        let animation2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity");
        animation2.fromValue = 0.0
        animation2.toValue = 1.0;
        let duration2 = Double(animationTime / Double(textLayers.count));
        animation2.duration = duration2*3.0;
        animation2.repeatCount = 1;
        animation2.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + Double(index) * duration2;
        animation2.fillMode = .forwards;
        animation2.isRemovedOnCompletion = false;
        textLayer.add(animation2, forKey: "\(index)+o");
        
        
        let position = textLayerPostions[index];
        
        let point = CGPoint(x: textLayer.position.x, y: position.y - 10);
        textLayer.position = point;
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position");
        animation.fromValue = point
        animation.toValue = position;
        let duration = Double(animationTime / Double(textLayers.count));
        animation.duration = duration*3.0;
        animation.repeatCount = 1;
        animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + Double(index) * duration;
        animation.fillMode = .forwards;
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false;
        textLayer.add(animation, forKey: "\(index)");
    }
}
```

Comment: For the blur, I find this idea interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16362762/1801544 it leaves you to search how to add blur

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS you can install Core Image filters on a layer and they are applied "live" to the layer. You could then build a Core Animation that would reduce the blur radius. That doesn't work on iOS.

I think your best bet is to create blurred versions of all 10 digits, and then animate an un-blurred version of a digit with a blurred version on top of it. During the animation, reduce the alpha of the blurred version to 0. That will have the effect of making the image appear to come into focus.

(For only 10 digits I would probably create blurred versions and save them as images. Alternately you could write code that would render the contents of any view into an offscreen renderer, capture it to a UIImage, then apply a Core Image Gaussian blur filter to the image. You' then install that blurred image on top of the un-blurred image as above.)